# how can I configure redis in cpanel for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, bullmq

Actually I'm try to build app that can support queue for email sending and I'm using bull queue package. We all know it require redis connection in background to run bull queue.

But here didn't find any resource to connect redis in cPanel for nodejs app.
I found only one option in software section as redis and click on the its says to enable and after enable its prompe me a socket link as **/home/haratiki/tmp/redis.sock**

[image]
[image]

My Code to create emailQueue instance as:

```
export const emailQueue = new Queue(EMAIL_QUEUE.NAME, {
    redis: ENV_CONFIG.redis.CONNECTION_URL   
});


emailQueue.process(ProcessNames.REGISTER_EMAIL, async (job: Job<SignupEmailQueueProps>, done) => {
    console.log("process is called");
    try {
        const res = await mailer.sendSignupVerificationEmail({
            verificationLink: job.data.verificationLink,
            to: job.data.to,
        });

        done();
    } catch (error: any) {
        done(error)
    }
});
```

My API to call this email queue action as:

```
app.post("/send-mail", async (req, res: Response<CustomResponseType>, next) => {
    const { to_email } = req.body;

    const mailerService = new EmailQueueService();
    const t = await mailerService.addSignupEmailInQueue({
        to: to_email,
        verificationLink: "https://www.google.com",
    });

    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
        status: true,
        message: "Email Send Successfully",
        detail: null
    })
});
```

**In Local Machine Its working normally**

When I build and deploy into cPanel I set CONNECTION_URL = /home/haratiki/tmp/redis.sock in .env
after success deployment.

I send request to send-email route its just hanging.
**Help Me To Configure Redis in cPanel**